# Should you access cleaned_data directly in views or have a method belonging to the given form that handles working with cleaned_data?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I started experimenting with django few afternoons ago and I have an app with a custom form in which I authenticate user the following way:

```
if form.is_valid():
   username = form.cleaned_data['username']
   password = form.cleaned_data['password']
   ... work with username and password ...
```

However, I also read on some webpage (witch I no longer have in my search history :/) that you should not access cleaned_data like that and that it is better to hide using of cleaned_data to a custom method. And do something like this:

```
if form.is_valid():
   form.process()
```

I don't think that it should matter much. Nonetheless, I'm curious which way is more preferable and django-like.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally implement a `save` method because `ModelForm` has a built in `save` method. But the pythonic way would be to use the best method name that you fell that describe the action and implement in the form.